Enter Bios/UEFI from desktop shortcut
I am currently dual booting windows and linux, i dont want to use grub because grub tends to get very flakey the longer things go on.
IS there a way for me to create a desktop shortcut in linux to immediately shut off and head to the bios? My reasoning for thinking this exists is that windows has the ability to boot to bios from the troubleshooting screen. I figure if i have this shortcut for both linux and windows, it will make the switching process easy as pie.

What you want is NOT possible.

linux: sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup - windows: shutdown /r /fw - how you set up those shortcuts is up to you now

You don't even need to "enter bios/uefi" for the "switching process". There's efibootmgr in Linux that allows you to set the "one-time" BootNext. There are also small utilities for Windows available on github, for example: https://github.com/pgaskin/bootnext (I don't remember if bcdedit can be used to set BootNext, but mostly it's gonna be a bit more "clumsy" even if it can.)

@TomYan - Ahh, I see now ... I get it. I focused on the words in the question, but you're right, something that switches without needing to go through BIOS is cleaner - I'll remove by comments regarding your suggestion :p

To be honest, when I dabbled in dual boot, I made Linux the "default", and used efibootmgr when I wanted to switch to windows, (in case I was too slow in grub)
